# Printing to a label printer from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, printing, webcam, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi I want to print from.

I searching a script that works like this:

**Push Button 1**

Prints...

```
"Hello World"
" - TIME - " (MM:HH)
" - DATE - " (DD-MM-YY)
```

...out on a paper.

**Push Button 2**
Then I need it to take a Photo from the USB webcam, then print...

```
"Hello World"
" - PHOTO - " (The Photo)
" - TIME - " (MM:HH)
" - DATE - " (DD-MM-YY)
```

...out on a paper.

Button 1 is what I really need now.
Hope anybody can help me.

I'm using a USB Brother Label printer.

Comment: Have you tried looking at something like: http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/printing-cups

Comment: that only give me a web based solution to install a printer,
not a python-script to printing

Comment: @askewchan, this question seems legitimate to me. Once you've followed your link and configured a printer, how do you get Python to print arbitrary text on it? I've worked with CUPS before and I still couldn't tell you off the top of my head.

Comment: You might get some hints from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316368/how-do-i-print-to-the-oss-default-printer-in-python-3-cross-platform

Comment: @MarkRansom You're right; I'm not the downvoter, though :)

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059930/can-you-print-a-file-from-python