# Python print to /dev/usb/lp0

Tags: python, linux, bash, printing, usb

I would like print to `/dev/usb/lp0` from my python code. In `bash` it is very simple: `echo 'apple' >/dev/usb/lp0`

I found [linemode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linemode), but this is not working. When I try to install it I get these errors.

```
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/linemode/renderers/xml.py to xml.pyc
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/linemode/renderers/xml.py", line 67
def __init__(self, source, *, max_width=None, prelude=True):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How I print to `/dev/usb/lp0` from python code?

Comment: If you want to send something to printer, here is solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059930/can-you-print-a-file-from-python

Comment: Striver: If I would like write to file: This ok. But I would like using /dev/usb/lp0 then I get error: Permission denied: '/dev/usb/lp0'

Comment: You can just create a regular textfile and use the lpr commandline tool to print this file.

Comment: Alexander Baltasar: It's not a pretty solution.

Comment: I created regular textfile and I wrote this python code: subprocess.call("cat file > /dev/usb/lp0", shell=True) But this is not working. (no error) But this bash is working: cat file > /dev/usb/lp0 Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working:

```
 with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'w') as printer:
            printer.write("Line 1\n")
            printer.write("Line 2\n")
```